# How to move a window created using MATLAB app designer to the center of screen?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

How can a window created by the MATLAB app designer be moved to the center of the screen?

Currently, I'm using `app.my_fig_main.Position` to update the location. However, this function can only set the following attributes `[left bottom width height]`.

When running the app on a screen with a different resolution, I should have some sort of `movegui` function that sets its location to `center`.

Unfortunately, `movegui` doesn't work in MATLAB's app designer environment.

Is there any way to do this in app designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I misunderstood your question, but you can obtain the current resolution using the `figposition` function. e.g. on my laptop:

```
>> figposition([0, 0, 100, 100])
ans =
  0   0   1366  768
```

indicating a resolution of 1366x768

You can then `set(gcf,'position', ... )` to the position you want, such that it's central.

You could even use `figposition` directly in there, in fact, to `set` the figure's position using percentages directly.

---

** EDIT: ** an example, as per request:

```
% Create Figure Window (e.g. by app designer; it's still a normal figure)
  MyGuiWindow = figure('name', 'My Gui Figure Window');

% Desired Window width and height
  GuiWidth = 500;
  GuiHeight = 500;

% Find Screen Resolution
  temp = figposition([0,0,100,100]);
  ScreenWidth = temp(3);
  ScreenHeight = temp(4);

% Position window in center of screen, and set the desired width and height
  set (MyGuiWindow, 'position', [ScreenWidth/2 - GuiWidth/2, ScreenHeight/2 - GuiHeight/2, GuiWidth, GuiHeight]);
```

Comment: After compiling my app, it will return this error: `undefined function 'gifposition' for input arguments of type 'double''` There isn't any problem when run my app in MATLAB environment.

Comment: you have a typo. figposition, not gifposition.